# Oauth discord auth with Electron app and Express api

Tags: discord, oauth, electron

I am facing a small theoretical difficulty regarding authentication with Electron.

For context, I have an Electron/Vue.js application and an API with Express. I want to implement OAuth authentication with Discord.

I have successfully generated my OAuth URL. My user with Electron opens this URL and authenticates; the redirection works well towards my API, which retrieves the code and then the token, and finally, I retrieve the user's information.

So far, everything works. Now, I am wondering how to keep my Electron app informed and display the user's information (username, avatar, etc.) to the user. I cannot pass parameters to the Discord authentication page, so I don't see how to identify which client is the one that connected.

Thank you in advance.

Clearly identify which Electron client has authenticated. Furthermore, since my client should not store the secrets of my Discord URL, what is the correct way to open this URL for my user?